# How to get the checkbox value selected in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using angular2. I have my html code like

```html
<select id="color" class="colorDropDown" (change)="signalSelected($event, 'color')">
   <option *ngFor="let color of colors" value={{axis}} [selected]="color == channelPropertyModel.color">
      {{color}}
   </option>
</select>
```

My typescript file is as follows

```html
this.colors = ["ORANGE", "WHITE", "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "CYAN", "SKYBLUE"];
```

On changing any color from the dropdown I am calling the method

```ts
signalSelected(event: any, selection: string) {
    //Add the newly entered value and the corresponding field name into the dictionary
    this.selectedUIInfo[selection] = event.currentTarget.value;
}
```

But I am not getting the selected color with event.currentTarget.value. Please suggest how to get the selected color from the dropdown.

Comment: sample mock json? data

Comment: how this is marked as answer where is the checkbox in the linked Plunker ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following example

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
  <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [ngValue]="c"> {{c.name}} </option>
</select>

class App {
  cities = [{'name': 'SF'}, {'name': 'NYC'}, {'name': 'Buffalo'}];
  selectedCity = this.cities[1];

  onChange(city) {
    alert(city.name);
  }
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KrhA94WgKgY9pp4T35O?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the checked property and assign it to the selected item as below

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedElement" (change)="changedval()">
     <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [ngValue]="color"> {{color}}</option>

</select>

<span *ngFor="let type of types"> 
      <input   type="checkbox"  [checked]="color===newElement" value="color"> {{color}}<br>
</span>




 changedval(){
     this.newElement=this.selectedElement;
     console.log(this.newElement)
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/uqY4vQr4jcEHh8V0Eh49?p=preview)**